# How to delete merge commits

Tags: git, github

I have certain merge commits on my master branch whenever I updated my repo from central repository. Now whenever I make a new branch from master these commits appear in pull requests which are very annoying. How can I remove these commits and avoid them in future while updating? 
I know that these kinds of questions have been asked but nothing has worked for me yet.

Comment: In the future; don't pull. Fetch and rebase instead. (Or pull, but with `--rebase`.)

Comment: Use `merge --no-ff`?

Comment: @mic4ael Won't that *create* a merge commit?

Comment: @Biffen, true, quick answer without thinking..

Comment: thanks @Biffen ...any idea how to remove the older ones?

Comment: @IshankGulati Nope, sorry. Are you absolutely sure you want to do that, though? Changing the history is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @Biffen The problem is these commits are getting piled up in all the pull requests.

Comment: If the pull request is to the master branch, then any commits on master shouldn't show up in the PR.

Is your master branch a fork of the main repository? If so, what you probably want to do is reset your master branch to match whatever commit the main repository's master is at, then rebase the commits from your PR onto this new master.

Comment: @Ajedi32 yes, my master branch is a fork of main repository. My master branch is 8 commits ahead of central repo's master which are all merge commits. I tried resetting but nothing happened.

Comment: @Ajedi32 thank you very much. this actually worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here is that your master branch contains commits (specifically, merge commits) which aren't part of the upstream repository. Because of this, any branches you base off of this master branch will also have those commits, so any PR asking to merge one of those branches to the upstream master will also include them.

To fix this, you can rebase your local master onto the master from the upstream repository. By default, `git rebase` ignores merge commits, so this should eliminate any superfluous commits from the branch's history. Assuming you have the upstream repository set up as a remote named `upstream`, you can do that like this:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git rebase upstream/master
git push -f origin master
```

Or alternately, if you're sure your master branch contains no changes that you want to keep which aren't already in the upstream repository's master branch (which, based on what you've stated in the question, should be the case), you can simply reset it to match the upstream master:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push -f origin master
```

After this is done, rebase your feature branches onto the new master branch:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
git push -f origin feature
```

This should remove the extra merge commits from your pull requests.

Comment: works very well, thank you, it's still not quite clear what is the effect of the rebase for me. Even because I usually have this problems with personal forks that i merge back to the main repo.
And so I don't get how i ca have commits that are not mine and are not in the upstream.

Comment: @colo It's hard to tell without seeing your repo, but one common way it can happen is if you have commits on the remote server that aren't in your local branch, then make a local commit and run `git pull`. By default that will automatically create a merge commit in your local history to merge the two diverging master branches (the local one and the remote one).

Comment: Yes I think at this point that this is the scenario that is usually creating problems to me, makes absolutely sense, thanks for the hint